# How to convert MP3 to WAV in Python

Tags: python, mp3

If I have an MP3 file how can I convert it to a WAV file? (preferably, using a pure python approach)

Comment: Decompressing MP3s is not an appropriate task to implement in Python.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, nobody has ever attempted to write an MP3 decoder in Python.  The resulting decoder would be terribly slow, and there is no sense in the project anyway; the more natural thing would be to make a Python module that wraps a C library.  Re-use the already-written and already-debugged C code, and don't try to reinvent the wheel.  I love Python too, but there are some projects that are not appropriate for Python and an MP3 decoder is one.

Answer (score 109):

I maintain an open source library, [pydub](http://pydub.com), which can help you out with that.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("/path/to/file.mp3")
sound.export("/output/path/file.wav", format="wav")
```

One caveat: it uses ffmpeg to handle audio format conversions (except for wav files, which python handles natively).

note: you probably shouldn't do this conversion on GAE :/ even if it *did* support ffmpeg. EC2 would be a good match for the job though

Comment: How to install ffmpeg in windows? Pip install ffmpeg not working

Comment: @Kaushal28 That's covered in the pydub docs https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#getting-ffmpeg-set-up

Comment: this will give an error  3rd line should be 
sound.export("/output/path/file.wav", format="wav")

Comment: @Jiaaro Why am I getting a `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Even thought the file is there.

Comment: @NikhilWagh The most common reason to get that error is because the ffmpeg executable can't be found

Comment: @Jiaaro How can ffmpeg installed on windows 10?

Answer (score 11):

This is working for me:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'audio.mp3',
                   'audio.wav'])
```

Comment: `pydub` (@Jiaaro's answer) is doing this in the background.

Comment: No matter how I do it it gives me "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: @Frobot have you installed ffmeg correctly?

Answer (score 5):

I think I am right person to answer this question because I am student who tried hard to get answer for this question. I am giving answer for Windows users but I think this may work with MAC OS too. But apt for windows.

Lets discuss answers in steps:

first check for pydub and ffmpeg package. If you computer dont have these packages then install pydub in you command prompt

```
                    pip install pydub
```

Next and imp thing is ffmpeg package which converts images to different formats. For this you should manually install this package. Let me give you reason why when we can use pip for installing package. First pip installs the package but it will not stores the path to the system. So computer cant recognize this package path. For this I suggest you to install manually but how.... dont worry will give you steps.

STEP 1:

#Present link

This first link that you have paste it in google

https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-release-essentials.zip

#Use for future students

But people will have question now this link might work what about future. For that simple answer is

https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

After typing this in google go to releases and download zip folder always don't download 7.zip.But thus is only when my first link will not work for future is any student search for answer.

STEP 2: After downloading the zip file from first step first link. Now make a folder in C drive. For this just click on my My PC, then OS(C:),make a new folder. Copy paste the zip file downloaded to this folder. Extract the zip file in this new folder. Now go into the folder and copy path of "bin" present in this folder from properties.

STEP 3:This is final step and imp one where you will set path. In search bar in your laptop search for "Edit the system environmental  variables". Then click on "environmental variables" at bottom for path. Here they are two parts in screen system variables and user variables. Now you have to search for path "Path" in system variable is you want to use for whole system. Double click on "Path" in system variables. A window appears where you have to choose "New". Here copy paste the path of bin folder. Then click on Ok in all and close all tabs.

Step 4:Check for correct installation of ffmpeg. In command prompt type ffmpeg now you will get the list of paths and its features. This shows you have finished your installation.

Step 5 : Download a mp3 file. If your have downloaded python then open IDLE prompt. The click on new in File a note pad appears. One imp point to remember here is copy paste the mp3 file where you python code is stored. Example If I want to save the python file in Desktop the mp3 file should be stored in desktop. I think you go an idea. Now copy paste the code which I am using

```
                import subprocess
                subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'ind.mp3','ind1.wav'])
```

then click on run module

you will get the conversion.

Thank you

This answer might help you. If you want code and method for converting speech to text code and method you can post me. I wish this answer for 10 min may save you hours.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBb_eYThfRQ

use this video for path configuration or step 3 for reference but copy path to system variables not user because whole system can use this package then. If my language is bad don't mind I think it is understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Install the module `pydub`. This is an audio manipulation module for Python. This module can open many multimedia audio and video formats. You can install this module with `pip`.

```
pip install pydub
```

If you have not installed ffmpeg yet, install it. You can use your package manager to do that.

For Ubuntu / Debian Linux:

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

When ready, execute the below code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

# files                                                                         
src = "transcript.mp3"
dst = "test.wav"

# convert wav to mp3                                                            
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
sound.export(dst, format="wav")
```

Check this [link](https://pythonbasics.org/convert-mp3-to-wav/) for details.

Answer (score 3):

For Those using windows 7 and above:

Step 1: This link will help you install ffmpeg:
[How to Install FFMPEG on Windows](https://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/)

Step 2: This code will help you convert multiple files from one format to another ( which of course is supported by ffmpeg)

```
import os
import subprocess


input_dir = r'C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Input\\Directory\\'
output_dir = r'C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Output\\Directory\\'
path_to_ffmpeg_exe = r'C:\\Path\\To\\ffmpeg-2022-YY-MM-git-blabla-full_build\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'

files_list = []

for path in os.listdir(input_dir):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(input_dir, path)):
        files_list.append(path)

for file_nm in files_list:
    print(file_nm)
    subprocess.call([path_to_ffmpeg_exe, '-i', os.path.join(input_dir, file_nm), os.path.join(output_dir, str(file_nm.split(".")[0] + ".wav"))])
```

Comment: For Step 1, provided link is not accessible right, all you need to do is check out the official builds & releases here; https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/ download the latest one, At the time of writing this, the latest build is from https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/latest/ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl.zip.