# Python: decode mp3

Tags: python, macos, mp3, decode

I need to decode an MP3 file with Python. What is a good library which can do that?

I looked at PyMedia but the project seems dead and it didn't worked on MacOSX. Then I found out about pyffmpeg but I didn't got it working on MacOSX so far.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does your code need access to the pcm data, or do you just need the mp3 to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did try an `easy_install` of PyMedia on OS X / Fink, and it did not work because it could not find the source.  This module does look quite dead…

One way of decoding MP3 is to call `ffmpeg` without going through pyffmpeg, but by calling ffmpeg using the standard subprocess module instead.

Comment: I think I will go the subprocess way. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You really need an external library. It'd be very difficult to do in Python with any sort of speed - see [How to convert MP3 to WAV in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049572/how-to-convert-mp3-to-wav-in-python) for some discussion.

How about python-mad? MAD being the 'mpeg audio decoder'; there's a python library. It'd give you the audio data. Never used it myself...

Answer (score 1):

I decided to code this myself based on subprocess and ffmpeg.

Some code can be found here:
https://github.com/albertz/learn-midi/blob/master/decode.py

Answer (score 1):

Please try https://github.com/sampsyo/audioread

It's fast, installs from pypi and works well