# Provision to convert mp3 to wav file in python and tutorial for audio processing using python [pymedia]

Tags: python

I am a new to python and matlab. I wanted to know whether is there any provision for converting a mp3 file to wav using any pymedia functions or  the function like'MP3WRITE' and 'MP3READ'in matlab? any good tutorial for audio processing tutorial using python?

Comment: I've referred (2010/2012 post -same question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049572/how-to-convert-mp3-to-wav-in-python  since it's now 2012 are there any improvements in python regarding audio processing?

Comment: Also I am using python 2.7 (portable python) and windows executable of pymedia  not found for this version (for version 2.4 its available)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. These basic tutorials are already documented in pymedia's documentation. [pymedia tutorial](http://pymedia.org/tut/) (Decompress mp3 file). Also binaries(unofficial) for pymedia for 2.7 could be downloaded [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Also Cygwin is a commonly used Linux emulator for Windows.