# Pydub installation and ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, virtualenv, pydub

I was trying to get raw sound data out of a `.mp3` file. Therefor I used the pydub module as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634128/how-to-extract-the-raw-data-from-a-mp3-file-using-python). I created a `venv` for this project and installed all necessary modules. But for some reason, pydub decided to give me an `FileNotFoundError`:

```
(venv) Python-IT:LightsDev pythonit$ which python
/Users/pythonit/Documents/Programmieren/Python/LightsDev/venv/bin/python
(venv) Python-IT:LightsDev pythonit$ which pip3
/Users/pythonit/Documents/Programmieren/Python/LightsDev/venv/bin/pip3
(venv) Python-IT:LightsDev pythonit$ pip3 list 
------------- -------
ffmpeg        1.4
pip           18.1
pydub         0.23.0
pyee          5.0.0
python-ffmpeg 1.0.5
setuptools    39.0.1
```

My exact code looks like that:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3('test.mp3')
raw_data = sound._data
print(raw_data)
```

and I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'
```

alongside this runtime warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

I don't know if it is me, but some similar questions stating I should install ffmpeg or python-ffmpeg won't work. I can even import the ffmpeg module but nothing happens. I can work with ffmpeg and load files but using it with pydub won't work.

EDIT: Today I changed to my windows machine and looked at the error in-depth. However I didn't manage to get it working, even with the solution provided in the comments (thank you though). I installed the ffmpeg binary as stated and i was able to get `ffmpeg` running in the shell, however not with `pydub`... I have no clue what is going on. I guess my mistake is very obvious and I am just not able to get it. Even not subprocess was able to solve this problem despite the fact, that I am able to **use ffmpeg in shell**. I even was able to convert the file using ffmpeg in shell...

```
 ffmpeg -i test.mp3 test.wav 
 > Output #0, wav, to 'test.wav':
```

I think I am close to solve the problem myself anyways, but thank you anyways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python convert mp3 to wav with Pydub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073278/python-convert-mp3-to-wav-with-pydub)

Comment: You need to install `ffmpeg` executable, not `python-ffmpeg` package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+RuntimeWarning%3A+Couldn%27t+find+ffmpeg+or+avconv

Comment: Might help! http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `ffmpeg` to your system, not python lib:

In Ubuntu:
    `sudo apt install ffmpeg`

In Windows:
    Just download the ffmpeg lib, extract, and add the `***\bin` path to the environment path

And Install both `simpleaudio` and `pydub` via `pip` to python lib **(I don't know why, but it work for me)**

Answer (score 0):

This error was also driving me crazy; Path was clearly the problem. There are several explanations like the one below that tell you to modify to C:\ffmpeg\bin (example: https://windowsloop.com/install-ffmpeg-windows-10/) and others that explain same did not work.

My solution was to modify the path to anaconda3 path: C:\Users\YOURPATH\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\bin

Then I needed to restart the computer for registry changes to take effect!

Don't forget that last step...

Unusual that ffmpeg can't create, use paths without user modification of registry paths (dirty)?