# Error while convering mp3 file to wav file format using python pydub module

Tags: python, pydub

I am trying to convert my mp3 file to wav format but its giving error like this

**My Code**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

src = "my_result.mp3"
dst = "final.wav"

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
sound.export("final.wav",format="wav")
```

**But this code is returning this kind of error**

```
C:\Users\91630\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)     
C:\Users\91630\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\91630\Searches\SciTech Dropbox\meruvu likith\PC\Desktop\python temp\mp3_wav.py", line 6, in <module>
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91630\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91630\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91630\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91630\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1022, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\91630\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1491, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: I think the problem is that it needs an external program such as `ffmpeg` or `ffprobe` to perform the conversion, but it could not locate that program.  Do you have either of those programs installed?

Comment: yes i've installed ffmpeg

Comment: Is it in your PATH?

Comment: idk bro how to check if its in my path or not?

Comment: If you type `ffmpeg` at the command prompt, does the command run?  Or does it say something like `ffmpeg: command not found`

Comment: yes its says not found

Comment: The term 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Whatever directory it is installed in, you need to add that directory to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252295/discussion-between-kartx-legend-yt-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ffmpeg is installed you need to add the path of ffmpeg to your environment variables' PATH. I'll explain for windows. First, find out where your ffmpeg is installed. Record that path, because you'll need it. Use the windows search for environment variables to bring up that system menu (like this https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0). Once there, click on the variable called PATH. Then, add and paste in the path of your ffmpeg. This should allow pydub to access ffmpeg.

This is similar to this question: [Pydub installation and ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480893/pydub-installation-and-ffmpeg) which may be of further guidance in other systems.