# How convert mp3 to wav in stream without saving to local files in python?

Tags: python, audio

I download mp3 from url(e.g. http://xxxx.mp3) using `response = urllib2.urlopen(url)` `html = response.read()`. How can I convert it into wav and also save the data in memory in variable without saving it to local files and read it out again?

Comment: Have you tried one of these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049572/how-to-convert-mp3-to-wav-in-python

Comment: I am using google app engine managed vm to decode mp3, which can be said as an external server. so the time is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit late. Anyway, You can solve that by :

1. call the mp3 file by AudioSegment function.
2. convert the mp3 file to wav form and save it in a variable.

see the code:-

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3_form) # 1
wav_form = sound.export(format="wav")   # 2
```