# Getting amplitude value of mp3 file played in Python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, audio

I am playing an mp3 file with Python on a Raspberry Pi:

```
output_file = "sound.mp3"
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(output_file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pass
sleep(0.2)
```

Now while the mp3 file is playing, I would like to get the current amplitude of the sound played. Is there a way to do this? The only examples I was able to find work on a microphone input but not with a file being played.

Comment: What is your purpose of getting amplitude? If you want the real value of amplitude, according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325804/how-do-i-find-amplitude-of-wav-file-in-python) you can't and you have to calculate it yourself. Are you looking for the normalized amplitude?

Comment: To build a VU meter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a VU meter code on [github](https://github.com/kmein/vu-meter/tree/master) working with microphone. You can easily change its input stream to wave file. <s>If you want to work with `.mp3` files, check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797934/get-the-amplitude-data-from-an-mp3-audio-files-using-python) for converting `.mp3` to `.wav` on air without storing data on storage.</s>

```py
import wave

def main():
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    try:
        # from wav file
        chunk = 1024
        wf = wave.open("kimi_no_shiranai.wav", 'rb')
        stream = audio.open(format =
                audio.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                rate = wf.getframerate(),
                output = True)
        
        data = wf.readframes(chunk)
        maximal = Amplitude()
        while data:
            # writing to the stream is what *actually* plays the sound.
            stream.write(data)
            data = wf.readframes(chunk)
            
            amp = Amplitude.from_data(data)
            if amp > maximal:
                maximal = amp
            amp.display(scale=100, mark=maximal)
        
        # from microphone
        # stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
        #                     channels=2,
        #                     rate=RATE,
        #                     input=True,
        #                     frames_per_buffer=INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK
        #                    )

        # maximal = Amplitude()
        # while True:
        #     data = stream.read(INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
        #     amp = Amplitude.from_data(data)
        #     if amp > maximal:
        #         maximal = amp
        #     amp.display(scale=100, mark=maximal)
    finally:
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        audio.terminate()
```

**Edit:**

for converting `.mp3` to `.wav` use this code. It doesn't have syncing problem. It stores converted wave into `BytesIO` buffer.

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("kimi_no_shiranai.mp3")
wav_form = sound.export(format="wav")
wf = wave.open(wav_form, 'rb')

stream = audio.open(format =
            audio.get_format_from_width(sound.sample_width),
            channels = sound.channels,
            rate = sound.frame_rate,
            output = True)
```

[SO link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449482/how-convert-mp3-to-wav-in-stream-without-saving-to-local-files-in-python)
[SO link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797934/get-the-amplitude-data-from-an-mp3-audio-files-using-python)

Comment: But there is no in syny audio output.

Comment: @Reto check the edit I made. It doesn't have syncing problem on my laptop. Hope works well on Raspberry Pi!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this to confirm, but it looks like you should be able to use the [`Sound` object's `get_volume()` call](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_volume).

Using your code above, you should just be able to do something like:

```py
output_file = "sound.mp3"
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(output_file)
pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume(0.5) # 50%, for example
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    current_volume = pydame.mixer.Sound.get_volume()
    sleep(0.2)
```

Or whatever else you wish to have happen.

Comment: get_volume only returns the volume but not the amplitude of the sound currently played. I feel I have to use pygame.sndarray but have not yet figured out how I can get the amplitude.

Comment: I see, so by "amplitude", you mean the sound level at any given moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to implement a VU meter for an mp3 file:

```
import pygame
import pygame.sndarray
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np
import time
from time import sleep

def play_and_vu(file_path):
    pygame.init()

    try:
        # Set the interval for updating the VU meter
        vu_interval = 0.02
        # Normalize factor for VU meter
        norm = 50

        # Load the audio file using pydub
        song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)
        sampling_rate = song.frame_rate

        pygame.mixer.init()

        # Load the sound file into Pygame mixer
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file_path)

        # Convert sound to a NumPy array
        sound_array = pygame.sndarray.array(sound)
        # Extract amplitudes from the left channel of the sound array
        amplitudes = np.abs(sound_array[:, 0])

        # Define the size of each VU meter update chunk
        chunk_size = int(sampling_rate * vu_interval)

        # Calculate the number of chunks
        num_chunks = len(amplitudes) // chunk_size

        # Calculate mean amplitudes for each chunk
        mean_amps = np.zeros(num_chunks, dtype=amplitudes.dtype)
        for i in range(num_chunks):
            start_index = i * chunk_size
            end_index = (i + 1) * chunk_size
            chunk_mean = np.mean(amplitudes[start_index:end_index])
            mean_amps[i] = chunk_mean

        # Normalize amplitudes and convert to integer
        max_amp = np.max(mean_amps[:])
        norm_amps = (mean_amps / max_amp * norm).astype(np.int32)

        # Play the sound
        pygame.mixer.Sound(sound).play()
        play_start = time.time()

        # Monitor the progress of the sound playback and display VU meter
        while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
            # Calculate the current VU meter value based on elapsed time
            value = int((time.time() - play_start) / vu_interval)
            # Ensure the index does not exceed the length of norm_amps
            if value > len(norm_amps) - 1:
                value = len(norm_amps) - 1
            # Display the VU meter bar
            print(f"|{'=' * norm_amps[value]}", end='\n')
            # Pause for the specified interval
            sleep(vu_interval)

    finally:
        pygame.quit()
```