# Is there any function in which .wav file will generate

Tags: python

I am stuck on the .wav file extension, I used "gtts" method to convert text into the speech and save the file and it is working perfectly but the problem is "gtts" only support the .mp3 extension but I need the output file with .wav extension.

So I am question is, if any function like "gtts" to convert text into speech and save the file with .wav extension?

or anyone who already done work on this module. Please share your opinion. Thanks

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for [mp3-to-wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049572/how-to-convert-mp3-to-wav-in-python)

Comment: the mentioned link is used to convert mp3 to wave file but somehow I am getting an error regarding invalid path. and that's the reason I gave up on conversion.

Comment: on which OS are you trying to do the conversion?

Comment: Windows Operating system

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing the link, it is now working after entering the environmental path of the lib.